# Calculate number of buzzs and their duration

Tags: signal-detection, stft

I'm trying to calculate the number of buzzs and their duration from a buzzer. I'm working with python and scipy lib and the short time fourier transformation capturing the audio with a microphone.

To calculate the duration of the buzzer i filter the stft by interested frequency (let's say 2.4khz) and then i check every dt counting how many of those dt have an amplitude over a certain threshold.

At first i tried to set an empiric threshold at 0.04 and most of the times it worked flawlessly problem is that randomly i've this kind of situation:

[image]

Where the signal amplitude has an "hole" dividing a single buzz in two buzzes. I tried to lower the threshold but then i started getting wrong values about durations (it should be 70ms and i got  80-90 and i'd like to keep the error lower than 10%).

I then tried to "smooth" the amplitude with the Savitzky-Golay filter, resolving the "hole" problem and obtaining the exact number of buzzs every time but losing too much informations about their duration.

[image]

Here there's part of the graph time/amplitude of the 2.4Khz component of my signal: the original (in blue) and the smoothed by the filter (in red). As you can see the "under threshold" part, marked in green, is bypassed by the filter.

I tried to normalize the signal, and working with percentage thresholds, but this way i lost even more information about durations specially if in the same session i record buzzes with higher and lower volumes.

Do yoy guys have any suggestions on how could i approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a time-domain bandpass instead of the STFT. Depending on how the buzzes line up with your STFT frames, the energy might get smeared out over multiple frames.

The bandpass method makes it easy to normalize. Just compare the energy of the bandpass signal to the total energy. If the bandpass has at least, say, 50% of the total energy, it's probably buzzing.

There are multiple way to "augment" this: you can leverage how long the band pass signal is high, you can compare the energy of the bandpass to that of a complimentary band stop, etc.